# Computing the fractional Laplacian of power function

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Is it possible to compute explicitly the fractional Laplacian (in $\mathbb R^n$) of a power function $|x|^p$?

Comment: Yes: $(-\Delta)^{\alpha/2} [|x|^p] = 2^\alpha \Gamma((p+n)/2) \Gamma((\alpha-p)/2) (\Gamma((p+n-\alpha)/2) \Gamma((-p/2))^{-1} |x|^{p-n-\alpha}$ whenever defined.

Comment: This follows easily from the composition rule for the Riesz potential kernel. See Theorem 3.1 in my survey [Kwaśnicki, *Fractional Laplace Operator and its Properties*, in: A. Kochubei, Y. Luchko, *Handbook of Fractional Calculus with Applications. Volume 1: Basic Theory*, De Gruyter Reference, De Gruyter, Berlin, 2019], [DOI:10.1515/9783110571622-007](https://doi.org/10.1515/9783110571622-007) for a rigorous statement and discussion.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Thanks! Could you clarify the $x$ dependence in your result? I expect it to be something like $-C_{N,\alpha} |x|^q$.

Comment: Ah, I noticed a typo in my previous comment: should be $|x|^{p-\alpha}$, not $|x|^{p-n-\alpha}$, sorry. This is exactly as you say, with $q = p - \alpha$, but the constant depends on $n$, $\alpha$ and $p$.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Thanks again. Oh, now I understand; in my browser the formula inside the comment is not properly displayed (I see it divided in two pieces with "whenever defined" in the middle). For the sake of clarity, could you please write it in an answer?

Comment: Sure, I will write it as an answer in a minute. Strange: the same rendering error happened here, but it disappeared when I refreshed the tab.

Comment: I noticed that Thm 3.1 is a wrong reference; should be Table 1. Once again sorry for all errors in the comments above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here it is:

> **Proposition:** Let $\alpha \in (0, \infty)$, $p \in (-n, \alpha)$, and
>   $$
>  f(x) = |x|^p .
> $$
>   Then $(-\Delta)^{\alpha/2} f(x)$ is well-defined for $x \ne 0$, and
>   $$
>  (-\Delta)^{\alpha/2} f(x) = 2^\alpha \frac{\Gamma(\frac{p+n}{2}) \Gamma(\frac{\alpha-p}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{p+n-\alpha}{2}) \Gamma(-\tfrac{p}{2})} \, |x|^{p - \alpha} .
> $$
>   Here we understand the right-hand side is zero if $\tfrac{p+n-\alpha}{2}$ or $-\tfrac{p}{2}$ is a non-positive integer.

This is sort of standard, as it follows from early work of M. Riesz on what is now known as the Riesz potential kernel. Sample reference is the first entry in Table 1 in my survey:

> M. Kwaśnicki, *Fractional Laplace Operator and its Properties*, in: A. Kochubei, Y. Luchko, *Handbook of Fractional Calculus with Applications. Volume 1: Basic Theory*, De Gruyter Reference, De Gruyter, Berlin, 2019, [DOI:10.1515/9783110571622-007](https://doi.org/10.1515/9783110571622-007)

but there are obviously older sources.