# Spectral fractional Laplacian of power-function $(-\Delta)^s x^{\alpha}$ in $(0,1) \subset \mathbb R$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, semigroups-of-operators, fractional-calculus

How can one compute the *Neumann spectral fractional Laplacian* of power function, $(-\Delta)^s x^{\alpha}$, with $\alpha >0$, in an interval $(0,1)$. I'm only aware of the formula in the whole space. We recall
$$(-\Delta)^\alpha u: \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sqrt 2 c_n\cos(\pi n x) \mapsto  \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sqrt 2 (\pi n)^{2s} c_n\cos(\pi n x),$$
where $c_n = \int_{0}^{1} \cos(\pi n x) u(x) dx$.

Note that in [Computing the fractional Laplacian of power function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361043/computing-the-fractional-laplacian-of-power-function) the formula is given in $\mathbb R^n$ instead of in the interval $(0,1)$.

Comment: the fact that the basis function $\cos(\pi nx)$ do not vanish at the end points of your interval creates difficulties in the definition of the fractional Laplacian; see page 18 of arXiv:1810.07028 --- Dirichlet boundary conditions are preferred to avoid these difficulties.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thanks! But (unfortunately) I need to consider the Neumann fractional Laplacian

Comment: the point is that it may not exist (at least not for $\alpha>1$)